# Delete Multiple Record from cakephp

Tags: cakephp

I am new in cakephp. I want to delete multiple record from checkbox but i did not know to use it. below is my code it post but not checkbox value.

```
<?php  echo $this->Form-enter code here>create(array('action' => 'deleteall'));?>
<?php echo $this->Html->Link('Delete',array('action' => 'deleteall'),array('confirm' => 'Are you sure you want to delete selected record?'));?>
<div class="row">
<?php echo $this->Session->flash();?>
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">Subjects</div>
                <div class="table-responsive">
                    <table class="table">
                        <tr>
                            <th><?php echo $this->Form->input('checkbox', array('type' => 'checkbox','name'=>'selectAll','label'=>false,'id'=>'selectAll','hiddenField'=>false));?></td>
                            <th>S.No.</td>
                            <th>Subject Name</td>
                            <th>Action</td>
                            <th>Question Bank Account</td>
                        </tr>
                        <?php foreach ($subject as $post): ?>
                        <tr>
                            <td><?php echo $this->Form->checkbox('subject',array('value' => $post['Subject']['subject_id'],'name' => "data['Subject']['subject_id'][]",));?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $post['Subject']['subject_id']; ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $post['Subject']['subject_name']; ?></td>
                            <td><a data-toggle="modal" data-href="<?php echo $this->Html->url(array('action'=>'edit', $post['Subject']['subject_id']));?>"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span> Edit</a></td>
                            <td><?php echo $post['Subject']['subject_id']; ?></td>
                        </tr>
                        <?php endforeach; ?>
                        <?php unset($post); ?>
                        </table>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php

echo $this->Form->end();?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `subjects_to_delete[]` as variable name in the view, which will generate an array with the IDs on the server.

```
<td><?php echo $this->Form->checkbox('subjects_to_delete[]',array('value' => $post['Subject']['subject_id'],'name' => "data['Subject']['subject_id'][]",));?></td>
```

Then you can use [`deleteAll` in CakePHP](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/deleting-data.html#deleteall):

```
$subjectsToDelete = $this->request->data['subjects_to_delete'];
$this->Subject->deleteAll(array('id' => $subjectsToDelete));
```

Comment: Notice (8): Undefined index: subjects_to_delete

Comment: should be `$this->request->data['Subject']['subjects_to_delete']` if your model is `Subject`. You can `var_dump($this->request->data)` to see exactly

Comment: You have probably solved this now but i had the same problem. You don't need the single quotes inside the name for data, thats how cakephp formats it, like `'name' => data[Subject][subject_id][]` then in controller `$this->request->data[Subject][subject_id][]`

Answer (score 0):

```
Use index.ctp this code
<td><?php echo $this->Form->checkbox(false,array('value' => $post['Subject']['subject_id'],'name'=>'data[Subject][subject_id][]'));?></td>

Add code in controller
public function deleteall()
    {
        if ($this->request->is('post'))
        {
            foreach($this->data['Subject']['subject_id'] as $key => $value)
            {
                $this->Subject->delete($value);
            }
            $this->Session->setFlash('Your Subject has been deleted.'));
        }        
        $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
    }
```