# Multipe Record delete not working CSRF- Cakephp

Tags: cakephp, csrf

I've found one of the answers [delete multipe record](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22472841/delete-multiple-record-from-cakephp) and tried following it, but I keep getting the same message:

> CSRF token mismatch.
>   Cake\Http\Exception\InvalidCsrfTokenException

```
'_Token' was not found in request data.
```

Edit :
The Delete button isn't working on thoses 4 Controller/Table (Users, Prospects, Contacts, Accounts, Leads) 
But they do work on my other table

Here is the

AppController.php

```
  <?php

  namespace App\Controller;

  use Cake\Controller\Controller;
  use Cake\Event\Event;


 class AppController extends Controller
 {

public function initialize()
{

    parent::initialize();
    $this->loadComponent('RequestHandler', [
        'enableBeforeRedirect' => false,
    ]);
    $this->loadComponent('Flash');

    $this->loadComponent('Security');
    $this->loadComponent('Csrf');
}
public function pr($arr){
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($arr);
    echo "</pre>";
    exit();
}
public function beforeRender(Event $event)
{
    if(!array_key_exists('_serialize', $this->viewVars) &&
        in_array($this->response->getType(), ['application/json', 'application/xml'])
){
        $this->set('_serialize', true);
    }

    if($this->request->getSession()->read('Auth.User')){
         $this->set('loggedIn', true);   
    } else {
        $this->set('loggedIn', false); 
    }
 }
 }
```

UsersController.php

```
  <?php
    namespace App\Controller;

    use App\Controller\AppController;
    use Cake\I18n\Time;
    use Cake\Event\Event;
    use Cake\ORM\TableRegistry; 
    use Cake\Mailer\Email;
    use Cake\Auth\DefaultPasswordHasher;
    Use Cake\Utility\Security;
    use Cake\Routing\Router;

    class UsersController extends AppController
    {
   public function beforeFilter(Event $event)
  {
    parent::beforeFilter($event);

   $this->Security->setConfig('unlockedActions', ['add']);

  public function initialize(){
    parent::initialize();
    $this->loadComponent('Paginator');
    $this->loadComponent('Security');
  }
   public function delete($id = null) {
if (!$this->request->is('post')) {
    throw new MethodNotAllowedException();
}
$this->User->id = $id;
if (!$this->User->exists()) {
    throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid user'));
}
if ($this->User->delete()) {
    $this->Session->setFlash(__('User deleted'));
    $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
}
$this->Session->setFlash(__('User was not deleted'));
$this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
}

public function deleteall()
{

     if ($this->request->is('post'))
    {
        foreach($this->data['Users']['user_id'] as $key => $value)
        {
            $this->Subject->delete($value);
        }
        $this->Session->setFlash('User has been deleted.');
    }        
    $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));

   /* $this->request->allowMethod(['post', 'delete']);
    $user = $this->Users->get($id);
    foreach ($user as $value) {
        $this->Users->deleteAll(['id'=>$value]);
    }
    return $this->redirect(['action'=>'index']);*/
}
      public function isAuthorized($user)
{
    // Admin has full access
    if ($user['role'] == 'Admin') {
        return true;
    }
    // User can view and edit own account only
    if (in_array($this->request->action, ['view', 'edit', 'delete']) && $user['id'] == (int)$this->request->params['pass'][0]) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}    

   public function verification($token){
        $userTable = TableRegistry::get('Users');
        $verify = $userTable->find('all')->where(['token'=>$token])->first();
        $verify->verified = '1';
        $UserTable->save($verify);
    }
```

And Here is a Working Delete on

NotesController

```
public function delete($id = null)
{
    $this->request->allowMethod(['post', 'delete']);
    $note = $this->Notes->get($id);
    if ($this->Notes->delete($note)) {
        $this->Flash->success(__('The note has been deleted.'));
    } else {
        $this->Flash->error(__('The note could not be deleted. Please, try again.'));
    }

    return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);
}
```

index.ctp

```
 <button type="submit" formaction="<?php echo $this->Url- 
 >build(['action'=>'deleteall']) ?>" class="btn btn-danger" 
 onclick="return confirm('Are yo u sure you want to delete users?')">
    Delete</button>
    </p>

 <th><input type="checkbox" class="selectall"/></th>

 <td><input type="checkbox" class="selectbox" name="ids[]" value="<?= 
 h($user->id) ?></td>"/></td>

<button type="submit" formaction="<?php echo $this->Url->build(['action' =>'delete', $user->id]) ?>" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure?')">Delete</button>
```

Comment: By not using the `FormHelper`, automatic fields (like the CSRF token) are not being added to your form, and the CSRF component is therefore rejecting the form data as invalid.

Comment: I tried disable //$this->loadComponent('Csrf'); now Im getting 
 '_Token' was not found in request data.

Comment: The `_Token` value is checked by the Security component. Any particular reason you don't want to use the Form helper? It integrates with both the CSRF and Security components, without any extra work on your part.

Comment: I do not need it for now its just im just testing stuff

Comment: It's been some time since I last used CakePHP, but why are you calling `$this->Subject->delete($value)` in the `deleteall()` foreach loop?

Comment: Please check i post i edited

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to disable CSRF and Security components. You can disable them for specific actions by adding below code in your controller's beforeFilter method.

```
$actions = [
    'delete',
    'deleteall'
];

if (in_array($this->request->params['action'], $actions)) {
    // for csrf
    $this->eventManager()->off($this->Csrf);

    // for security component
    $this->Security->config('unlockedActions', $actions);
}
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: This didn't help im afraid, it's a little more tricky im editing the first post apparently delete works on other Controller Table but  not in thoses 5 ( Users, Prospects, Contacts, Accounts, Leads